# Error build gradle when creating firebase

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, admob, google-play-services

I've tried to add firebase to my project, but I got stuck. Here is my build gradle project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here is my build gradle module app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vlad.comentariibac"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.4"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The line 
    `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'`
is highlighted with red and is saying that all `google.android.gms` libraries must use the exact same version specification. I need some help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe the error is self-explanatory. You must use the same version number for admob: compile `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android, Firebase is actually part of Play services.  When you build with Firebase, all of the SDK versions must match your Play services SDK versions.  As it stands now, you are asking for 9.0.0 of play-services-ads and 10.0.1 of firebase-core.  These need to match, and the latest version of the entire set of Play services SDKs is 10.0.1.